# How to use the title attribute of a div to add a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a class to a div by using the title attribute. Currently the alert is correct. However the class isn't added.

JS Part:

```
function index(clicked_id){
   alert(clicked_id);
   $('#sticky').attr("title", +clicked_id).addClass("glow");
}
```

HTML Part:

```
<div id="sticky" class="" title='sticky1' onclick='index(this.title)'</div>"
```

Comment: Better to use a `data-attribute` than `title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("[title*='sticky']").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("glow");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2xecs1mo/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I got your question right but I understood that you want to filter|find you div by the title. So maybe this code will help you:

```
function index(clicked_id){
   alert(clicked_id);
   $('#sticky [title="' + clicked_id + '"]').addClass("glow");
}
```

Comment: Space between `#sticky [title="'` indicate descendant of `#sticky` ?

Comment: yes! you can also use `>` to say that is the first deep descendants

Comment: Selector at posted solution does not reference `#sticky` element. `js` at Question returns expected results. `html` is missing `>` at `#sticky` tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead just pass `this`:

```
onclick='index(this)'
```

now in the function:

```
function index(el){
   var e = $(el).attr('title');
   $('#sticky[title="'+e+'"]').addClass("glow");
}
```

As the element itself is the target one then just use this:

```
function index(el){
   $(el).addClass("glow");
}
```

or better to go unobtrusive, remove the inline event handler and use this way:

```
$('#sticky').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).addClass("glow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do it like that? Can't you just set the class on the element clicked?

JavaScript

```
function index(el){
    $(el).addClass("glow");
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="sticky" onclick='index(this)'></div>
```

Comment: nice copy. i would say.

Comment: You had not written the last part of your answer when i wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

`js` at Question returns expected results. Missing closing `>` at `html` `#sticky` `<div>` tag at

```
onclick="index(this.title)"
```

following `onclick` attribute . Additionally,

```
+
```

should be removed at

```
+clicked_id
```

at `.attr()` setting `title` . `javascript` `+` operator attempting to convert `clicked_id` `String` to `Number` when placed before string

```js
function index(clicked_id){
   alert(clicked_id);
   $('#sticky').attr("title", clicked_id).addClass("glow");
  
}
```

```css
.glow {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="sticky" class="" title="sticky1" onclick="index(this.title)">click</div>
```